# why some WPF controls do not appear in the toolbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Some WPF control do not appear in the toolbox panel in the visual studio 2008 sp1, like webbrowser. 
Is this by design?

Answer (score 0):

Some controls were added in WPF version 4 (Visual Studio 2010). For example, WebBrowser. That is why it does not show up in Visual Studio 2008 (which supports only upto WPF 3.5 SP1).

Comment: Check the document, it is indeed in the 3.5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: My mistake. It was added with 3.5 SP1. Do you have SP1 installed for your Visual Studio 2008?